# show only the final iteration from a loop

Tags: java

I have been checking StackOverflow for a while and now it was finally time for me to register. I couldn't find my question on the site, so I thought I will ask it myself. I have copied my code down below.
I am doing this for a school assignment. It does everything it is supposed to ( find the second smallest number) but, the output is not what i want it to be. I have tried placing the out.printf statement somewhere else but it just doesn't work. What happens first is that the first 2 numbers are automatically assigned to smallestNumber and secondSmallestNumber, the assignment says that the first number entered should always be smaller than the second. After that it goes to the loop and compares all numbers. And finally it should print out the final secondSmallestNumber. But it just prints all. I have tried several things and i can't get this right. Help me out please?

```
EDIT : teaching assistant told me I can't submit my assignments online in the event of fraud. So I'm sorry have to delete this code.
```

Comment: `secondSmallestNumber` is defined outside of the `while` loop meaning that it is not bounded to exist only in the loop, which means that you can print the value of it outside (i.e. after the loop) which will give you the expected result. It will only print once because it wouldn't be in the loop.

Comment: I have gotten 3 the same answers, and although i understand what you are all talking about it just doesn't work. Could you help me further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others - you should move the printing outside the loop. Also at the end you shout `flush` your `printstream`. So try this:

```
    package module2;

    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SecondSmallest {

        PrintStream out;

        SecondSmallest() {
            out = new PrintStream(System.out);
        }

        void start() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            out.printf("%s", "Enter multiple numbers divided by a space and close with Enter: ");
            int newNumber;
            int smallestNumber = in.nextInt();
            int secondSmallestNumber = in.nextInt();

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                newNumber = in.nextInt();

                if (newNumber < smallestNumber) {
                    secondSmallestNumber = smallestNumber; 
                    smallestNumber = newNumber;

                } 
            }
        //moved here to print only once 
           out.printf("%s%d\n", "The second smallest number is : ", secondSmallestNumber);
        //flush output stream 
           out.flush();
        }   


        public static void main(String[] argv) {
            new SecondSmallest().start();
        }
```

Comment: thanks! I will find out what flush does. But it worked

Answer (score 2):

To do something repeatedly, you put it inside of a loop.  Thus, to *not* do it repeatedly, put it *outside* of the loop.

Comment: could you show me where exactly? i have tried to put it on almost every line, mostly the console just doesn't give any feedback outside of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Move `out.printf("%s%d\n", "The second smallest number is : ", secondSmallestNumber);` outside of the while loop.

Comment: the problem with that is that the console shows nothing.